# Conditional VLOOKUP With Specific Text

Tags: excel, vba

I am looking for a VBA code that could help me apply VLOOKUP on column "L" but only cells with specific text.

For example if the value in cell on column "L" is "#N/A", then it should replace it with the value returned from the VLOOKUP. If the value is not "#N/A", it should not change the actual value in the cell.

Here is the code that I tried

```
Range("L:L").NumberFormat = "mm/dd/yyyy"
lastrow6 = Range("K" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
Range("L3").Formula = "=IF(ISNA(VLOOKUP(A3,'[Ref_Data_Vivar.xlsx]Legacy PCO'!$A$2:$B$25628,2,0)),"""",IF(ISERROR(FIND(""#N/A"", VLOOKUP(A3,'[Ref_Data_Vivar.xlsx]Legacy PCO'!$A$2:$B$25628,2,0)))"
Range("L3").AutoFill Destination:=Range("L3:L" & lastrow3)
Range("L:L").value = Range("L:L").value
```

Comment: Instead of asking the internet for "a VBA code", give it a try first, and then ask a specific question about VBA.  There are many VBA tutorials out there.

Comment: I have looked at several tutorials however, I couldn't find one that could help me resolve my query. I did try a code that is below but didn't seem to work `Range("L:L").NumberFormat = "mm/dd/yyyy"
lastrow = Range("K" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
Range("L3").Formula = "=IF(ISNA(VLOOKUP(A3,'[Ref_Data_Vivar.xlsx]Legacy PCO'!$A$2:$B$25628,2,0)),"""",IF(ISERROR(FIND(""#N/A"", VLOOKUP(A3,'[Ref_Data_Vivar.xlsx]Legacy PCO'!$A$2:$B$25628,2,0)))"
Range("L3").AutoFill Destination:=Range("L3:L" & lastrow3)
Range("L:L").value = Range("L:L").value`

Comment: Look at the VBA [IsError function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg278547.aspx).

Comment: ... and what if the VLOOKUP returns another `#N/A`?

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should do the trick:

```
Sub FindErrorInRange()

Dim cell As Variant
Dim rng As Range

'data range:
Set rng = Sheet1.Range("A1:A10")

For Each cell In rng

    'checks for '#N/A error:
    If CVErr(cell) = CVErr(xlErrNA) Then
        'do something here:
        MsgBox ("error found")
        'example:
        cell.Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.Lookup() '<-- insert your lookup values
    End If

Next cell

End Sub
```